# How to call abstract method in super class constructor in TypeScript 1.8

Tags: angularjs, oop, abstract-class, typescript1.8

I need to call an abstract method from the abstract class constructor.
This worked fine until TypeScript 1.8.x.

```
export abstract class BaseController {
   field1:any;
   constructor(){
       this.initialize();
   }

   initialize():void{
       this.field1 = this.getField1Value();
   }

   abstract getField1Value(): any;
}

export class DerivedController extends BaseController{
    constructor(private dataService:any){
        super();
    }

    getField1Value():any{
        //do some data manipulation and then return a object
        return this.dataService.getField1Value();
    }
}
```

How to make something like this to work?
Those are Angular controllers. So basically what I'm doing is initializing some fields in derived controllers.

Sample TS Playground:
[TSPlayground sample](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=abstract%20class%20BaseController%20%7B%0A%20%20%20field1%3Aany%3B%0A%20%20%20constructor()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.initialize()%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20initialize()%3Avoid%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.field1%20%3D%20this.getField1Value()%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20print()%7B%0A%09%20%20%20alert(this.field1)%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20abstract%20getField1Value()%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20DerivedController%20extends%20BaseController%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20dataService%3Aany)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getField1Value()%3Aany%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fdo%20some%20data%20manipulation%20and%20then%20return%20a%20object%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.dataService.getField1Value()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20DataService%0A%7B%0A%09constructor()%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09getField1Value()%7B%0A%09%09return%20%22three%22%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20e%20%3D%20new%20DerivedController(new%20DataService())%3B%0Ae.print()%3B%0A)

Comment: This works on http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground without problems. Which version of TS this stopped working?

Comment: 1.8.5. I'm using it now

Comment: the problem is that i have this html:
<div ng-init="vm.field1.form = userEditForm">
 and the vm.field1 is undefined.

Comment: Actually I found the problem... the problem is that this.dataService is undefined in the DerivedController. Still don't know how to do it.

Comment: And it doesn't work in TS Playground, see edit...

Comment: You didn't say you have to instantiate the derived class ;) I tried the code sample you provided. It worked. The one with the `new`, yes, that's not working. I'm just here to make things clear for people.

Comment: did you resolved that ? how ? i'm with the same problem

Comment: Nope, not jet. Although i moved to Aurelia.